# How to block Onesignal push notifications on Android?

Tags: android, onesignal

I know I can receive them in `Broadcast` `OnReceive()` but I cannot prevent Onesignal for creating a `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all down voters who does not leave a comment. Nice move..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to setup a OneSignal `NotificationExtenderService` class and add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` as a `Service`.

```
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;

public class NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample extends NotificationExtenderService {
   @Override
   protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
        // Read properties from result.

      // Returning true tells the OneSignal SDK you have processed the notification and not to display it's own.
      return true;
   }
}
```

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<service
   android:name=".NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

See the OneSignal Android [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding) documentation for more details.

Comment: Tnx @jkasten this has helped me a lot. Gave me an idea that I can send the parameters I need in key-value pairs in Onesignal dashboard.

Comment: @Majstor can you please provide code how can we hide onesignal notification

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal I updated my answer to whats available in the 3.0 SDK.

Comment: thanx alot @jkasten

Comment: also you can add following line to service tag in AndroidManifest:

android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"

Comment: @AliZarei Thanks for the Android Oreo (8.0) required update. Just added it to my answer

Comment: class not found anymore

Answer (score 0):

> NotificationExtenderService

has not found anymore

Use this one instead:

> OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler

and add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension"
        android:value=".notifications.RemoteNotificationReceivedHandler" />
```

Also, visit the following link, [Service Extensions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions)